# Why won't my furnace turn on?

Tags: furnace, heater

My furnace will not turn on. Unless:

Switch off.      Unplug Fresh Air Intake Motor (a MagneTek ). 
   Turn on (hear a click).      Plug motor back in.     Heat fires. 
   Blower distributes

Its a natural gas Underwriters Laboratories MMHA-07AAHR-02. I've cleaned the motor out and oiled. Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. UL doesn't make furnaces; it looks like yours was made by Nordyne, and they don't make them anymore. Do you hear the "click" if you turn on the furnace while the air intake motor is attached?

Comment: Yes Nordyne is right. If the motor is attached then no click occurs.

Comment: I'm no expert, but perhaps there's a problem with the controller board?